How to test internal workings of a function that returns an object that was mocked?
I am still somewhat new to JUnit and writing tests for my Java Springboot application.
I want to test a function within a service that looks like this:
public UploadedScanQueryFile store(MultipartFile file) {
        
    UploadedScanQueryFile newFileRecord = new UploadedScanQueryFile();
        
    newFileRecord.setUploadDateTime(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    try {
        newFileRecord.setFile(file.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.debug("Exception when trying to get bytes form file : {}", ex.toString());
    }
    newFileRecord.setFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());

    return fileRepository.save(newFileRecord);
}

fileRepository is a MongoDB service.
My JUnit test looks like this:
@MockBean UploadedScanQueryFileRepository fileRepository;

@Test
void doValidStoreTest() throws IOException {
    String filename = "ScanQueryUploadTestFile.csv";
    File testCSVfile = new ClassPathResource(filename).getFile();
    InputStream testCSVInputStream = new FileInputStream(testCSVfile);
    MockMultipartFile testCSVMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(filename, testCSVInputStream);

    UploadedScanQueryFile result = new UploadedScanQueryFile();
    result.setFileName(filename);
    result.setId(99);
when(fileRepository.save(org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any(UploadedScanQueryFile.class))).thenReturn(result);

    storageService.store(testCSVMultipartFile);

    assertEquals(99, result.getId());

}

My problem is that I have no real way to test that the method is doing what it should because the object it returns is simply the Mocked object that I pass in.
The internal workings set various parameter values, but I can't check them because they're internal to the method and not exposed to the test (as it's the mocked value that is returned).
Does anyone have any suggestions on how best to test in this scenario?
I have written the above test class, which basically runs the method to ensure that it doesn't throw an exception, but that doesn't test the internal workings are doing the correct thing,

You are writing a unit test for the public UploadedScanQueryFile store(MultipartFile file) method, so what you do is perfectly fine. However, if you want to test UploadedScanQueryFileRepository.save, you need to write a separate unit test for it.

Mockito provides an ArgumentCaptor mechanism that should be helpful here.
Class level:
    // declare mock beans...

    @Captor 
    ArgumentCaptor<UploadedScanQueryFile> fileRecordCaptor;

In your test, you can verify that the repository save was invoked and capture the a reference to the newFileRecord parameter:
    Mockito.verify(fileRepository).save(fileRecordCaptor.capture());
    var savedFile = fileRecordCaptor.getValue();
    /// your assertions... 
    assertEquals(expectedFilename, savedFile.getFilename())


Thanks so much. This works a treat!
One small correction to your code: Mockito.verify(fileRepository).save(fileRecordCaptor.capture());

Glad to hear it helps, answer updated with your correction, many thanks @BjarneSlamon for pointing that out

To test internal workings of a function, you must pass this function mocks of all the objects it uses in its work. Your function uses MultipartFile, UploadedScanQueryFile and FileRepository, so you must make the objects:
MultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("some name", "some content".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
UploadedScanQueryFile uploadedScanQueryFile = Mockito.mock(UploadedScanQueryFile.class);
FileRepository fileRepository = Mockito.mock(FileRepository.class);

You should not instantiate UploadedScanQueryFile inside your function, you should pass an instance of UploadedScanQueryFile as a parameter:
UploadedScanQueryFile store(UploadedScanQueryFile newFileRecord, MultipartFile file);

In the test you should call your method:
storageService.store(uploadedScanQueryFile, file);

and then check what methods your function called, the order in which it called them, and the parameters it passed:
Mockito.verify(uploadedScanQueryFile).setUploadDateTime(Mockito.any(LocalDateTime.class));
Mockito.verify(uploadedScanQueryFile).setFile(file.getBytes());
Mockito.verify(uploadedScanQueryFile).setFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());
Mockito.verify(fileRepository).save(uploadedScanQueryFile);


I need to instantiate the UploadedScanQueryFile somewhere though and this is where it makes most sense to so. The only other place to do it would be in the Controller that handles the post request at the start. I feel it makes more sense to instantiate it here as it is entirely related to the implementation of my Storage Service.

@BjarneSlamon In this case, you increase the coupling of your code, violating the Dependency Inversion Principle, which makes it difficult to test, reuse, and further modify. For example, if you need to use a different implementation of UploadedScanQueryFile, you will have to make changes to your Storage Service.
